# Can both starting roads be placed on the same settlement?

Tags: catan

According to the rules,

- we can place settlements only beside roads leading to it or away from it.
- we can place roads beside roads or settlements.

During initial placement, we have the choice of placing two settlements and roads in successive turns. If we follow the above rules, Can we do the following placement?:

[image: Initial Settlement Scenario]

There doesn't seem to be any rules in the rule book regarding this, and it is an exceptional case to the above mentioned rules!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From [the official game rules](https://www.catan.com/files/downloads/catan_base_rules_2020_200707.pdf), under "Set-Up Phase":

> The starting player places a settlement on an unoccupied intersection of their choice, then places a road adjacent to this settlement. The other players then follow clockwise. Everyone places 1 settlement and 1 adjoining road.
>
> Once all players have built their first settlement, the player who went last in the first round begins round two. That player builds their second settlement and its adjacent road.

So no, a player may not place their second road adjacent to their previously-placed settlement, or the road leading from it, because the above rule explicitly instructs that the 2nd road is built adjacent to the 2nd settlement.

Comment: The only exception is when the road connects both settlements ;-)

Comment: Woah.....is this rule written as part of the almanac provided or on the catan site?
Even so...really appreciate the help...Thanks!

Comment: @Karthik - I'm fairly certain this is part of the official rules. Check the part that describes the setup phase.